# Is there a Java utility to verify if a string is a valid HTML escape character?

Tags: java, html, escaping, html-escape-characters

I want a method in the following format:

```
public boolean isValidHtmlEscapeCode(String string);
```

Usage would be:

```
isValidHtmlEscapeCode("A") == false
isValidHtmlEscapeCode("&#1513;") == true // Valid unicode character
isValidHtmlEscapeCode("&#x5E9;") == true // same as 1513 but in HEX
isValidHtmlEscapeCode("&#78975332;") == false // Invalid unicode character
```

I wasn't able to find anything that does that - is there any utility that does that?
If not, is there any smart way to do it?

Comment: What about `&amp;`, `&auml;` and `&customEntity;`?

Comment: I don't mind a function that deals with those - but it is not my requirement (in other words - I'm impartial regarding it)

Comment: Why can't you just check if it starts with `&`, ends with `;` and middle portion consist of (i) a-z, 0-9 (ii) # followed by digits (iii) #x followed by hex digits?

Comment: @SalmanA I was hoping for a smarter way to do it - I don't like reinventing wheels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static boolean isValidHtmlEscapeCode(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return false;
    }
    Pattern p = Pattern
            .compile("&(?:#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)|#([0-9]+)|([0-9A-Za-z]+));");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(string);

    if (m.find()) {
        int codePoint = -1;
        String entity = null;
        try {
            if ((entity = m.group(1)) != null) {
                if (entity.length() > 6) {
                    return false;
                }
                codePoint = Integer.parseInt(entity, 16);
            } else if ((entity = m.group(2)) != null) {
                if (entity.length() > 7) {
                    return false;
                }
                codePoint = Integer.parseInt(entity, 10);
            } else if ((entity = m.group(3)) != null) {
                return namedEntities.contains(entity);
            }
            return 0x00 <= codePoint && codePoint < 0xd800
                    || 0xdfff < codePoint && codePoint <= 0x10FFFF;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's the set of named entities http://pastebin.com/XzzMYDjF

Comment: Thanks, this was the best solution for my issue - I slightly modified it by adding a `^` at the beginning of the pattern and a `$` at the end so for strings like `hello &#123; world` it will not return `true`

Comment: @RonK cheers, yeah I use this regex for extracting html entities and forgot to modify it ^^

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a perfect solution, but you can use Apache Commons Lang:

```
try {
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(code).length() < code.length();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: StringEscapeUtils doesn't handle anything in the &#xxx; format. So basing my code on it will not work

Comment: It does indeed, unescapeHtml4 contains NumericEntityUnescaper, so it should handle them

Comment: looks like it throws `IllegalArgumentException` when you pass invalid entity, so I've updated my solution a bit

Answer (score 2):

you might want to have a look at Apache commons StringUtils:
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml(java.lang.String)

with the unescapeHtml you could do sth. like:

```
String input = "A";
String unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(input);
boolean containsValidEscape = !input.equals(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be the method you wanted:

```
public static boolean isValidHtmlEscapeCode(String string) {
String temp = "";
try {
    temp = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml3(string);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    return false;
}
return !string.equals(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try matching using a regular expression:

```
public boolean isValidHtmlEscapeCode(String string) {
    return string.matches("&;#([0-9]{1,4}|x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4});");
}
```

Or to save some processing cycles you can reuse the regex for multiple comparisons:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("&;#([0-9]{1,4}|x[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4});");

public boolean isValidHtmlEscapeCode(String string) {
    return pattern.matches(string);
}
```

The source of the regex can be found at [RexLib.com](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=html%20encoded)

Comment: Not bad - but `isValidHtmlEscapeCode("&#99999;")` will return true

Comment: @RonK the regex has been changed to correct the length constraint.

Comment: @RonK `&#99999;` is valid... in decimal, up to `&#1114111;` is valid.

Comment: @Esailija - thanks, so length validation is not enough - the value of the number also needs to be validated.

Comment: @RonK among other things, such as character references that would amount to lone surrogates, which I don't think htmlUnescape accounts for. Even chrome and firefox inconsistently treat `&#xd801;` as a valid entity, transforming it to `&#xFFFD;`